# CSS rotated div border shows odd outline

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying rotate a div with a border.
The border has the same color as the background.
A very thin line appears between the border outline and the background.
Here is my code below.
I'm trying to get rid of the weird line.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 50px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I tried multiple browsers.

I could fix this by using another div instead of a border, but I'm more interested in getting the border to work as expected.

Comment: That's very strange. I'd be really interested in finding out why this happens, rather than simply how to fix it (which is rather easy)

Comment: I know you have a solution to this, but I've added a bounty to try to understand it a little better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple fix of this is by using `backface-visibility: hidden`.

When an element rotates, it seems that the rendering of `transform: rotate()` may cause the back face of it to be shown, as if in 3D perspective.

This possibly lead to the `background-color` of the back face (a mirror image the element's front face) overflowing the border edge in this case.

`backface-visibility: hidden` fix it by rendering the back face invisible, as shown in below example.

On side note, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) did mention that `backface-visibility` has no effect on 2D transforms, which indicates that this behavior of `transform: rotate()` to have perspective is more accidental than expected.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 50px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div + div {
  /*   fixed here */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Lovin' the emoji comment 

Comment: It's really interesting that this fix works, given the info in the MDN link.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting one as it only appears with the rotate transformation. You can remove it using outline to paint over the thin line with a border which will also not affect the positioning of it as follows:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 50px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  outline-offset:-1px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! I had to change the border to 49px for my div to end where I intend it. I'm still hoping to get an explanation for the current behavior and a working border without workarounds.

Comment: It's the first time I've seen it too so thanks for highlighting it. It sounds as though it's the rendering engine that's got a glitch. There's a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894977/white-lines-appearing-when-using-transform-scale-function which looks more effective than mine

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox only**

My best guess is that there are rounding issues with the 3D rotation on the `Z-axis` in browser graphics functions. Rotation on the `X-axis` and `Y-axis` show no issues. It seems the size of the element drawn is rounded down (smaller), while the browser calculates with the actual or rounded up values. The difference will be a narrow gap where the element `background-color` is able to bleed through. I used `red` in the snippet to show this.

Both `transform: rotate(..)` and `transform: rotateZ(..)` show the same issue when rotation is other than `0deg` (usually the purpose of rotation).

**To resolve the issue** (Firefox only!!) use `transform-style: preserve-3d` with the element being rotated.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 3rem;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 50px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.test {
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* voila! background colored border is gone... */
  margin-top: 4rem; /* create some distance */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the border is still there om both `divs` in chrome 107.0.5304.107

Comment: @JonP I would probably go for the newer answer `backface-visibility: hidden` too, but it does not explain why it happens, as per bounty request. Another problem I have with it is that if a backface *has* to be visible the issue returns. Adjusting my answer to 'Firefox only'. Still digging deeper into this...

Answer (score -1):

try like below, no need border, just simply use margin.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
  }
div{
width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 0px;
    /* border: 50px solid black; */
    margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: A margin can't have a color.

Comment: 1) have you try this code, this has same output as required .               2) in this already use background-color

Comment: Yes, I tried the code. Thank you very much for submitting it! But the border is a requirement

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
  }
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 0px;
  /* border: 50px solid black; */
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```